# Product topology versus compact-open

Tags: general-topology

Let $Y = \prod_{i\in I}X_i$ have the standard product topology over $X$ (all $X_i$ s are equal), and $Z = C(I,X)$ with the compact-open topology. If $I$ is discrete, are Y and Z equivalent? This seems true but I can't find any confirmation and am not sure how to formally prove it. I may just be confused as many formulations of the product topology give a basis in the terms of a product of subsets rather than a subset of products

If I'm understanding, each $A \in Y$ is a subset which contains all products where to each $i_1,i_2,\dots ,i_n$ is assigned any arbitrary open set X from a specified collection $O_1,O_2,\dots ,O_n$. The set contains all products of this form, regardless of what values they assign to each of the other elements of I.

Then A should exist in Z from the intersection with each k of the mappings which take the compact set $\{i_k\}$ to an $O \in O_k$, taking the union to capture each $O_k$. Each $B \in Z$ sshould also be of this form (since in particular each compact set in the discrete I is finite, and all of these cases can be formed from finite intersection or infinite union of this case.

Am I correct in how I'm understanding these? Is there a good way to formally equate these two?

Comment: Oh, I checked over lots of other suggestions and searched for a while but couldn't find that. I'll delete this if they're the same thing

Comment: There's no need to delete. This post might help other people having the same question in the future!